# tensorflowでの画像ファイルを保存する方法はありますか？

Tags: tensorflow, 深層学習

tensorflowを用いて自己符号化器を作成しているのですが、出力によって再現された画像を画像ファイルとして全て書き出す方法はありますか？　画像はMNISTの数字データを使用しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tensorflowのapiには画像データをエンコードするコードはあるみたいです。
例えば、出力された画像ファイルをfileとすると

```
image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(file, format=“rgb”)
```

でimageにjpeg画像としてカラーでエンコードします。
あとはこれを保存するだけなので、pythonの標準apiを使って

```
with open(“ファイル名”, “wb”) as fb:
    fb.write(image)
```

って感じだと思います。

tensorflowのホームページを見てもらえるとわかると思いますが、jpegもしくはpngでエンコードできるみたいです。

Comment: 回答して頂きありがとうございます。早速以下のようなコードを追加してみました
for i in range(10000):
    image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28), format='grayscale')
    with open("decoded.jpg", 'wb') as fb:
          fb.write(image)
すると

Comment: 先ほどのコメントの修正版です。

回答して頂きありがとうございます。早速以下のようなコードを追加してみました
for i in range(10000):
    image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28), format='grayscale')
    with open("decoded.jpg", 'wb') as fb:
          fb.write(image)
すると
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for 'EncodeJpeg' (op: 'EncodeJpeg') with input shapes: [28,28].
のようなエラーが出てしまいます。原因としては出力された画像が(10000,28,28)のテンソルであることだと思うのですが、これらを画像データ、またはテンソルとして保存する方法はありますか？知識不足で申し訳ないのですが教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 先ほどのコメント失礼しました。なんとか解決する事ができました。ご協力頂きありがとうございました。